# Create a perfect circle having two lines of text

Tags: html, css

Using html/css, I want to create a perfect circle with two lines of centered text like in the image below.  What is the cleanest/most elegant way that will work in modern browsers? Do I have to declare a width and height or can I just use padding/border-radius?

[Here is the **JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxX7B/1/)

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="score">92 <br>
    <span class="text">Overall</span>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
.score {
   font-family: Arial;
   text-align: center;
   background: #DCAA38;
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding: 15px;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: #fff;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: -20px !important;
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: "cleanest" is very subjective. What browsers do you want to support?

Comment: define a width and height of equal proportions for the circle or border-radius 50% will do what you see in your fiddle. Aside that, I don't see your method as being particularly unclean (assuming you are doing the tricks for full support of border-radius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here:   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P7Kf/) you need to create square first

```
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
}
.score {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    background: #DCAA38;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -20px !important;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a reason why the score and the text are not centered even tho they both have `text-align: center;`? http://jsfiddle.net/qxX7B/3/

Comment: The `position:absolute;` currently on the `.text` in the fiddle is set and that will negate any text alignment (that positioning needs to be completely gone).

Comment: Here's a version that does not require any positioning - http://jsfiddle.net/qxX7B/14/

Answer (score 0):

Hey like the Kai Qing said change your class like this

```
.score {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    background: #DCAA38;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height:70px;
    width:70px
}
```

I have added equal height and width attributes.

For responsiveness you can use em values instead of pixels

Comment: Yeah I may look into em's. Is declaring a heigh/width the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes the height width are required in order to radius property to work. 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dimensions:

```
.score {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is declaring dimensions the only option?

Comment: The key is you want the width and height to be the same in order to make it a circle rather than an ellipse, which was happening in your JSFiddle since the H2 was falling to it's inherited dimensions in the DOM of a longer width than height. So if you declare it to be the same size (any size) it will render perfectly round with border-radius:50%

Answer (score 0):

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MatsKruger/5G7B5/) It's two different methods one uses tables and the other uses transform.
Personally i like the second one best because i don't have to use so many divs.

```
.perfect-circle2 {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: 100;
        background: #222;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    height: 0;


    }
    .content2 {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .number, .text {
        display: block;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .number {
        font-size: 200%
    }
    .text {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
```

To create these examples i used code from:

[Vertical align](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

[Propotional resizing](http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements/)